# Excel formatting - Integers with decimal point and thousand separator

Tags: excel, number-formatting

All the data that come from the source are integers:

```
345819404
1093
28495
```

The only "tool" I have at my hand is Excel-style formatting options to turn it into:

```
3,458,194.04
10.93
284.95
```

Basically I can't convert those using `/ 100`. So far I have two different styles that give me both components but I can't merge them together.

`#,##0` gives me thousand separator

`#"."00` places the dot as a "fake" decimal point

How can I get this work together?